# Drupal modules not showing in configurations

Tags: drupal, configuration, module, settings

I have inastalled a bunch of modules, but the configuration page shows only default ones. I have cleared the cache several times and the issue is not connected to the memory limit. Any ideas how to fix this or how can I track the error?

Comment: Please make sure you have placed your decompressed module folders under /sites/all/modules or /sites/name/modules (in case of a multisite Drupal installation).

Comment: What do you mean by "installed"? Copied them? Where?

Comment: Yes, make sure each module folder is _placed_ inside /sites/all/modules (or /sites/sitename/modules in multisite). It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by updating drupal 7 core to latest drupal version (7.36). I hate this CMS.